# What is the purpose of CDI @Produces annotation on a field?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi, java-ee-6

I think I understand the purpose of CDI @Produces combined with factory method:

```
@Produces
public TimeLogger getTimeLogger() {
    return new TimeLogger(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"), Calendar.getInstance());
}
```

However I don't really see how the following can be usefull equivalent:

```
@Produces
TimeLogger timeLogger;
```

Since `timeLogger` would be null in the second case, then how does it serve any purpose? How can point to some factory that can provide TimeLogger instance? Do I need to add qualifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's try again.

Suppose I have a field in a managed bean.  It is typed with `Foo`:

```
private Foo foo;
```

Suppose I set that field in a method somewhere using ordinary Java things:

```
// Let's pretend this is called from our constructor.
private void initialize() {
  this.foo = goGetAFooFromLDAPOrSomething();
  // yay, now foo is set to something that I went and got from somewhere;
  // I just went out and got it; I didn't do anything fancy involving
  // CDI
}
```

Suppose now that elsewhere in my application I want to use a `Foo` but I really really don't want to go through this headache again, and simply want to indicate that a `Foo` is one of my requirements, so, being a good CDI citizen, I'd just like to `@Inject` a `Foo`:

```
// In some other class somewhere.
// Hey, CDI, get me a Foo that was produced elsewhere,
// however you do it.
@Inject
private Foo injectedFoo;
```

If we stop right here, this injection point won't be satisfied.  No one at the moment "makes" a `Foo` in such a way that CDI will ever know about it.

I can satisfy the injection point by simply adding `@Produces` to the managed bean's `foo` field:

```
@Produces
private Foo foo;
```

After all, we populated this field manually ourselves, and then indicated to CDI that it can "make" a `Foo` by simply returning this field's value when someone calls for a `Foo` to be injected somewhere.

Does that make sense?

Qualifiers are no different in this case than they are in any other: they are another way to indicate what kind of `Foo` is made or injected.  If I wanted to inject a `@Yellow` `Foo`, then I would indicate my desire like this:

```
@Inject
@Yellow
private Foo injectedFoo;
```

...and I would then have to make sure that something, somewhere, produces a `@Yellow` `Foo`.  In this stupid example, it could be set up like this:

```
@Produces
@Yellow
private Foo foo;
```

Comment: Just tested it and makes sense, I was missing qualifier in this case - thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose is to bridge CDI's dependency injection with, perhaps, some other dependency injection mechanism, such as Java EE's `@Resource` injection.

In general, putting `@Produces` on a field means that when someone else calls for an object of the field's type, then the object will be "produced" by the contents of this field, whatever they happen to be, and regardless of how they came to be that way.

Comment: You described purpose of @Produces, but didn’t really address any of my questions regarding differences and qualifiers